# Process to Auto Create Case when Budget is updated or removed

Tags: workflow, process-builder, formula-field

We have about 10 budget fields that are filled out on an Opportunity. Whenever these budget fields are edited or nulled within 8 days of a "Target Date", we want a case with the subject "Budget Changed" to automatically generate for that Opportunity.

Is there any way to utilize Process Builder to prompt such a specific task?

edit - What would be the recommended Condition / Operator that would need to be chosen in order to signify that the budget field was edited or nulled? Currently, I have another process that generates a case when any of the budgets is set to greater than $0.

Comment: Is there any way to utilize Process Builder to prompt such a specific task: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a Date field say "Budget Field Modified Date". Add a new workflow rule, that checks `ISCHANGED(Budget_Field__c)` and then do workflow field update to set `Budget_Field_Modified__c = TODAY()`.

Then a process builder, checks if `Budget_Field_Modified_Date__c = Target_Date__c + 8`, then choose action as "Create a Record" (case object).

Just change the Target Date condition check as per your needs (+ or - 8).  This is just psuedo code.

Comment: It seems that if I add this checkbox, the workflow will always mark the box as "True" since we always input budget data into the 10 budget fields. How would it be possible to make it so that the checkbox is only marked true when the budget is changed within 8 days of the target date?

Comment: oh in that case,  I updated my solution - create a Date field instead of checkbox field.